# how to get back to parent form after submiting child form in jsp

Tags: forms, jsp

I have created Sales voucher form in jsp. If customer is not registered then it needs to be registered first so i have given link in my form to customer.jsp

When customer entry gets submitted after all validation then it needs to back on salesvoucher.jsp

Could any one please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added button in Sales Voucher jsp to open customer master jsp instead of link and call the ShowModalDialog() method on click event of button.

```
<input id="createcustomer" type="button" value="Create New Customer"  onclick="window.showModalDialog('http://localhost:8080/AA/CustomerMaster.jsp','self');">
```

And used ajax in Customer Master to store records. To reload and revert back to the Sales Voucher  I have used window.opener.location.reload() in body of Customer Master

```
<body onunload="window.opener.location.reload(); self.close();">
```